# Assigning a Rank based on duplicate values of a column SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2012, and I have the following table:

```
OrderNumber
1000
1000
1000
1013
1013
1025
1025
1025
1025
```

I need to return an index for EACH order number, like this:

```
OrderNumber    Rank
1000            1
1000            2
1000            3
1013            1
1013            2
1025            1
1025            2
1025            3
1025            4
```

My code is as follows:

```
SELECT OrderNumber,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY OrderNumber) as Rank
FROM orders
    INNER JOIN...(the rest is fine)
```

Due to the join the order Numbers are repeated, but I need a way to get the nth occurrence of an Order Number.
ROW_NUMBER() assigns a unique number to every row, while RANK() assigns the same number to each order.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `partition by`:

```
SELECT OrderNumber,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OrderNumber ORDER BY OrderNumber) as Rank
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want:

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT OrderNumber,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY OrderBy ORDER BY OrderNumber) as Rank
FROM orders
    INNER JOIN...(the rest is fine)
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE Rank = ?
```